# Puppet: Include all subclasses automatically?

Tags: module, vagrant, puppet

I am configurating multiple systems with vagrant and puppet (CentOs). I have a module which should make them all known to each other by hostname (module 'hosts').

Every machine generates a subclass called like itself, with the own hostname and ip (ex.: hosts::machine1).

Now my problem is that they have all to be included in init.pp of the host module to be executed. The machine names and count are different from run to run.

At the moment i include the subclasses each by hand ( include hosts::machine1, include hosts::machine2).

So now to my question:
Is there a possibility to include all subclasses of a module? or of a folder?

Or what would be a better way to solve this?

Greets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not required to generate Puppet code in classes. You could generate top-scope code instead.

```
# manifests/machine1.pp
host { 'machine1': ip => 'x.x.x.x' }
```

Make sure to configure Vagrant to use the whole `manifests/` directory **as the manifest**. Then all resources declared in the contained `.pp` files will be honored.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether Vagrant can be made to talk to PuppetDB. If it can, you should probably use [exported resources](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/latest/reference/lang_exported.html) for this.

Each node exports its own entry

```
@@host { $fqdn: ip => $ipaddress, tag => 'my-cluster' }
```

Each note imports all entries

```
Host<<| tag == 'my-cluster' |>>
# also realize own export:
Host<|  tag == 'my-cluster'  |>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But i am provisioning my machines after each other.. so the ip of host 2,3,.. would not be in this cluster for host 1! Or am i wrong?

Comment: Good point - this only really makes sense if `puppet` keeps running periodically on your VMs (not really Vagrant's style).